# Partial Upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS from the update manager. After upgrade it was not successful and on reboot I found the system having partial upgrade(some icons are from Ubuntu 20.04). On running

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

the following error is seen.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-7 gcc-8-base:i386 gir1.2-mutter-2 gnome-themes-extra
  gnome-themes-extra-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf libarmadillo8 libatomic1:i386
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-locale1.65.1 libbsd0:i386 libcdio17
  libctemplate3 libdouble-conversion1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libffi6:i386 libffi7:i386 libgeos-3.6.2 libgeotiff2 libgmime-3.0-0 libip4tc0
  libip6tc0 libiptc0 libisl19 libllvm10:i386 libmozjs-52-0 libmutter-2-0
  libmysqlcppconn7v5 libnm-gtk0 libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0
  liborcus-0.13-0 libpcre3:i386 libpcrecpp0v5 libperl5.26 libpodofo0.9.3
  libpython3.6-dev libstdc++-7-dev libstdc++6:i386 libsynctex1 libtexlua52
  libtinfo5:i386 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libunistring2:i386 libva2:i386
  libvdpau1:i386 libvsqlitepp3v5 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mysql-utilities
  mysql-workbench-data python-asn1crypto python-cffi-backend
  python-cryptography python-dnspython python-enum34 python-idna
  python-ipaddress python-mysql.connector python-paramiko python-pexpect
  python-ptyprocess python-pyasn1 python-pyodbc python-pysqlite2 python3-click
  python3-colorama python3.6-dev vdpau-driver-all:i386 x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus fonts-opensymbol gdal-data gir1.2-rb-3.0 libaec0 libaom0 libarmadillo9
  libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4
  libavutil56 libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0
  libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71.0
  libbrlapi0.7 libcfitsio8 libcharls2 libcodec2-0.9 libcoin80c
  libcollada-dom2.4-dp0 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libdc1394-22 libgdal26
  libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff5 libgfortran5 libgpgmepp6
  libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgsm1 libhdf5-103 libjson-c4 liblilv-0-0
  libmysofa1 libnetcdf15 libogdi4.1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopengl0
  libopenscenegraph160 libopenthreads21 liborcus-0.15-0 libpodofo0.9.6
  libpostproc55 libproj15 libqxp-0.0-0 libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-style-breeze librhythmbox-core10 librubberband2 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libserd-0-0 libsnappy1v5 libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libsz2 libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libva2:i386
  libvidstab1.1 libx264-155 libx265-179 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libzmf-0.0-0
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 proj-data rhythmbox rhythmbox-data scribus scribus-data
  uno-libs-private
Suggested packages:
  libopenal0a libsimage-dev libbullet2 geotiff-bin gdal-bin libgeotiff-epsg
  graphicsmagick-dbg ogdi-bin breeze-icon-theme serdi sndiod sordi opencl-icd
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gnome-codec-install
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder icc-profiles scribus-ng-doc scribus-template
Recommended packages:
  va-driver-all:i386 | va-driver:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  appmenu-qt libdbusmenu-qt2 libebook-1.2-19 libgdal20 libhdf5-100 libnetcdf13
  libogdi3.2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-script
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 qdbus qt-at-spi uno-libs3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaom0 libarmadillo9 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavresample4 libavutil56 libboost-date-time1.71.0
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0
  libboost-thread1.71.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcfitsio8 libcharls2 libcodec2-0.9
  libcoin80c libcollada-dom2.4-dp0 libdc1394-22 libgdal26 libgeos-3.8.0
  libgeotiff5 libgfortran5 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libhdf5-103 libjson-c4
  liblilv-0-0 libmysofa1 libnetcdf15 libogdi4.1 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libopengl0 libopenscenegraph160 libopenthreads21 liborcus-0.15-0
  libpodofo0.9.6 libpostproc55 libproj15 libqxp-0.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libserd-0-0 libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libswresample3 libswscale5
  libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libvidstab1.1 libx264-155 libx265-179 libzmf-0.0-0
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 uno-libs-private
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dbus fonts-opensymbol gdal-data gir1.2-rb-3.0 libaec0 libdap25
  libdapclient6v5 libgeos-c1v5 libgpgmepp6 libgsm1 libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze librhythmbox-core10
  librubberband2 libsnappy1v5 libssh-gcrypt-4 libsz2 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2
  libva2 libva2:i386 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss proj-data rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data scribus scribus-data
29 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 21 to remove and 1148 not upgraded.
162 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/83.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 158 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 299569 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dbus_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) over (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dbus_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1_a
md64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm': Is a d
irectory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dbus_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Unable to work around the problem. How can I get a full installtion of Ubuntu 20.0?

Comment: IMO: Reinstall the OS.

Comment: Any other way? I am able to boot into the OS.

Answer (score 2):

At first remove the problematic object/directory with

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci
```

then clean downloaded packages by

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and resume upgrade procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This folder /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci doesn't exist.

Comment: Then run all other commands. If you have long error output - please upload it to pastebin for analysis, share a link here.

Comment: The same error after running `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/c1XHr1cX

Comment: Really you can try `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/dbus_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` and then retry full process above.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z5xAZGpp

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci`; then `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci` . And then retry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128156/discussion-between-zircons-and-n0rbert).